# Strange Coding Methods In java

Tags: java, legacy

I have come across 2 samples of code from a legacy system that i'm at a loss to understand why someone would code like this. The app is in Java and is about 10-15 years old.

It seems so inefficient to hard to understand done like this.

```
if(condition) {
    String[] hdtTmp = { "Range (Brand):", "Build Region:", "Design:", "Plan (Size):", "Facade:", "Region:" , "Internal Colour", "External Colour"}; 
    hdt = hdtTmp;

    String[] hddTmp =  { p.RangeName, brName, p.HomeName, p.Name, f.Name, "North", "Red", "Blue"};                          
    hdd = hddTmp;

    hddTmp = null;
    hdtTmp = null;
}
```

I do not understand why you would not just assigned it to the attribute in the first place? And since the hdtTmp and hddTmp are inside the block why make them null?

```
max = hdt.length -1;

for(int i=0; ; i++) {
    // do some stuff here
    if(i == max) 
        break;
}
```

Again, it seems that the original programmer didn't know how for loops worked?

They never taught this when i did my degree, so my question is, Why would anyone write code like this?

Comment: Is there a problem here? We could only speculate as well as you could.

Comment: Chances are someone just didn't know very well what they were doing. If `hddTmp` are thread/method local then assigning to null makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Setting local variables to null... Well back in the 90s, some old Sun documentation suggested that this would help, but it's been so long and that information is probably no longer available as it is no longer correct.  I have run into this in a lot of old code and at this point it does nothing since local variables loose the reference to the object as soon as the method exits and GC is smart enough to figure that out.

The for() loop question is more of someone building a loop with exit criterion inside the actual loop.  It's just unfortunate coding style and probably written by a relatively junior developer.

This code definitely seems like someone coding java after learning C/C++.  I have seen enough of it, C/C++ people were taught to clean up after allocation and assigning to null was something that made them happy (at least the ones I have worked with back in the day).  Another thing they did was override the finalize method, which is bad form in java but was the closest thing they had to destructors.

You may also see infinite loops with stopping condition inside like:

```
for (;;) { 
     // Do stuff
     if (something_happened)
         break;
}
```

Old (bad) habits die hard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a narrow use case for nulling variables in the general case.

If the code between assigning `null` and the end of the variable's scope (often the end of the method) is longish running, nulling gives an earlier opportunity to GC the object previously referenced.

On the surface this is a micro optimisation, but it can have security benefits: if a memory dump or other similar snapshot (eg by a profiler) was to occur it could (very slightly) reduce the chance that sensitive data was part of the dump.

These "benefits" are pretty tenuous though.

The code in the question however is utterly useless.

Comment: It seems such a performance hit when you assign a local temporary variable only to reassign that temporary to a global one and then null the temporary to have its scope end just afterwards.

Comment: @dion I meant the general concept of nulling variables. The code in the Q however is utterly useless.